# Query optimization and comparison with impala

Tags: sql, optimization, impala, rapidminer

I am working on PowerBi and use SQL server as database. I used views or direct tables as source to PowerBi . My views are simple select queries with simple joins. I am not finding any scope for query optimizations. Query execution takes time in SQL and table has millions of data increasing day by day.

Now I am thinking to use impala as well as SQL server. I am getting clean data from Rapidminer. I didn't use impala before. So I have some doubts. Please answer if you can. I have zero knowledge of impala.

1. Can we create connection between rapid miner and impala? then what will be the steps? google give me some steps which is difficult to understand.
2. Can we create connection between impala and sql?
3. Can we create view on impala and create joins in views? I know we can create view as well as joins in impala. But my question is can we create it together?
4. suppose SQl and impala connection is made then suppose I have one table from impala and one table from sql server management studio. can I join both tables in impala? for this can we create connection between impala and sql server management studio?
   5.Can I use all tables or views created in sql to impala (after making connection between sql and impala). That means my tables or views are in sql. but I am fetching data in impala.
5. All tables stored in sql server. can I do join operation on these tables in impala.
   7.Can I make views in impala using tables which are stored in sql
   8.Can I create all tables in impala and do etl operation like sum, add, dateadd in impala
   9.Can I create all tables in impala and do etl operation like sum, add, dateadd in power query
   10.Can I create views from sql and put it in impala table. and use in power query
6. Can I create all tables and views with joins in impala?
   12.How can I optimise my query in sql and if I run same query for same data in impala then my execution time will reduce or not?

My SQL query is like this
create view as test
select * from table a
inner join table b on a.id=b.id
inner join table c on b.name=c.name
go
output is 3000000 row. increasing day by day
also instead of using view I use table directly. but execution time is not decreasing.